Tabulator.js - custom column calculation for number of invalid cells in column?
For a number of columns I want to put a topCalc count of the number of invalid cells in that column.
In the example below I can show at the top of a column the number of invalid cells in a table using table.validate().length(), but since I don't know how to access the calling column object in the function, I can't do column.validate().length(), which is what I need.
Is there a way to be able to access the column object (e.g. I tried const column = this;)?
Sample code and the result shown below and also in this JS Fiddle

var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    col1: 2,
    col2: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    col1: 'hello',
    col2: 33,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
        col1: 55,
    col2: 'goodbye'
  }
];

var mySum = function(values, data) {
    let calc = 0;
    values.forEach(value => {
       if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
            calc += value;
        }
    });
    return calc;
};

const countInvalidCells = function(values, data, calcParams) {
        const column = this;
    return "Invalid: " + table.validate().length;
};

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  selectable: true,
  /* selectableCheck: function(table, row) {
    console.log(table, row)
    }, */
  columns: [{
      title: "Column 1",
      field: "col1",
      width: 200,
      validator: "integer",
      topCalc:countInvalidCells,
      bottomCalc: mySum,
    },
    {
      title: "Column 2",
      field: "col2",
      width: 200,
      validator: "integer",
      topCalc:countInvalidCells,
      bottomCalc: mySum,
    },
  ],
});

